# Loading XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am loading redirects from a xml file.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfRedirectModel xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RedirectModel>
    <Time>0001-01-01T00:00:00</Time>
    <oldUrl>/301/</oldUrl>
    <newUrl>/alloy-track/</newUrl>
    <type>1</type>
    <Id>6d278d45-aab1-4fa2-953f-f03963a29ff8</Id>
  </RedirectModel>
</ArrayOfRedirectModel>
```

And where I read the xml file the code looks like this.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
string mappath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ClientResources/SeoCache");
xDoc.Load(mappath + "//cache.xml");
XmlNodeList xmlSelectedNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("RedirectModel");   

foreach (XmlNode node in xmlSelectedNodes)
{
```

But my "xmlSelectedNodes" stays "null".

I want to get the "oldUrl" and the "newUrl" in a string variable so I can use it.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you should be using `ArrayOfRedirectModel/RedirectModel` - but it would be simpler to use LINQ to XML. Are you able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the root element completely, try:

```
XmlNodeList xmlSelectedNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ArrayOfRedirectModel/RedirectModel");
```

Your original code would also work if you selected nodes from the root node itself:

```
XmlNodeList xmlSelectedNodes = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("RedirectModel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its should be

> XmlNodeList xmlSelectedNodes =
>   xDoc.SelectNodes("//ArrayOfRedirectModel/RedirectModel");